# I am unable to view my app on the android studio emulator screen

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am unable to view my app on the android studio emulator screen. I have tried using GPU host, increased Ram, fixed HAXM, fixed intel VT-X. I think the problem may lie with my code. Since i am new to android and java. I will also be including the java file and the xml file. I have tried restarting, reducing API levels among other things. the android logcat is also attached. This app tries to add two numbers.

java code:

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.PersistableBundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity{


    Button add;
    TextView ans;
    EditText n1, n2;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState, PersistableBundle persistentState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        ans = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        n1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        n2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int a,b,c;
                a = Integer.parseInt(n1.getText().toString());
                b = Integer.parseInt(n2.getText().toString());
                c = a+b;
                ans.setText(""+c);

            }
        });
    }

}
```

xml code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:id="@+id/layout1">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="numberSigned"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:gravity="right" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="numberSigned"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:gravity="right" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="SUM"
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_marginTop="35dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="0"
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_marginTop="43dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

android logcat:

```
04-10 04:01:54.310    2143-2159/com.tandh.myfirstapp D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Render dirty regions requested: true
04-10 04:01:54.310    2143-2143/com.tandh.myfirstapp D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x7f10fcffae80, tid 2143
04-10 04:01:54.410    2143-2143/com.tandh.myfirstapp D/Atlas﹕ Validating map...
04-10 04:01:54.450    2143-2159/com.tandh.myfirstapp D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x7f10fcffb3c0, tid 2159
04-10 04:01:54.480    2143-2159/com.tandh.myfirstapp I/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Initialized EGL, version 1.4
04-10 04:01:54.500    2143-2159/com.tandh.myfirstapp D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
04-10 04:01:54.550    2143-2159/com.tandh.myfirstapp **W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented**
04-10 04:01:54.550    2143-2159/com.tandh.myfirstapp **W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0x7f10fcffe700, error=EGL_SUCCESS**
```

manifest code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.tandh.myfirstapp" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: You mentioned a log cat in your original post, can you post it if you are getting an error?

Comment: I see no logcat - do you get the error from an empty project?

Comment: i have just uploaded the logcat...  since i am also new to stackoverflow I am unable to upload a snapshot of my emulator...

Comment: can you post your manifest file.

Comment: uploaded the manifest...

Comment: What does "unable to view the app" mean?

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that you have the necessary **ARM EABI v7a System Image** and the **Android SDK** of the target API. For instance if you are developing an app for API 15, you need to check if you have the System Image and the SDK of API 15.

Comment: I seem to have up-to-date SDK. Except for the obsolete SDKs, I have installed all from the Android SDK manager in the android studio. Is there any other solution. The problem still persists.